# I encountered the java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error when I used the RallyRestToolkitForJava

Tags: rally

I used the RallyRestToolkitForJava Api to get all the story and task data for analyzing purpose, but I found that I can get some of the data and terminate  with the error of `java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
       at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doRequest(RallyRestApi.java:318)
       at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doGet(RallyRestApi.java:460)
       at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.get(RallyRestApi.java:266)
       at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.get(RallyRestApi.java:254)
       at com.rallydev.rest.Tool.getByRef(Tool.java:44)
       at com.rallydev.rest.GetStroy.main(GetStroy.java:31)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.rallydev.rest.GetStroy.main(GetStroy.java:42)`

Comment: 401 indicates wrong credentials passed to restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),username,password); as if the connection is  reset and different credentials are used in the middle of the run.

Comment: Thank you for you replying, do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: Verify the credentials used in the code - 401 means wrong username/password. Verify that the user is not locked. Test connecting to Rally when running your code from a different network environment.